# how to combine results from 2 elasticsearch indexes with different layouts

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch with 2 different indexes. In one index there is a field called `physical_location` which contains a lat en lon subfield. in the other index there is a field called `program_run.geolocation` with the same nested lat and lon.

Now we want to plot documents from both indexes on a map in our client web application. we tried using a boolean query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "10km",
          "physical_location": {
            "lat": 53.193078596551715,
            "lon": 6.783202751724139
          }
        }
        },
        
        {
          "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "10km",
          "program_run.geolocation": {
            "lat": 53.193078596551715,
            "lon": 6.783202751724139
          }
        }
      } 
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

but this does give an error, because elastic cant find the first field in the second index and the second field in the first index.

What is the best way of fixing this?

- Is there a server side way of combining queries for different indexes with different layouts without errors?
- or is it more handy to combine on the client? (and how to deal with aggregate counts in that case)
- or is the only way out reindexing and making the names the same in both indexes? (requires lots of refactor work).

Answer (score 2):

## Someone over at the elasticsearch forum had the right answer.

you can make aliases for field names inside the index mappings. and so you can define a "location_for_search" field that is mapped via the aliases to the right fields.

Working example is here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-combine-results-from-2-elasticsearch-indexes-with-different-layouts/293659/2

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT : THIS ANSWER IS INVALID FOR ABOVE QUESTION,PLEASE FIND UPVOTED ANSWER**

I think first option can be achieved, in Java RestHighLevelClient, it has a constructor available which can take multiple index names and a search query.

```
Constructs a new search request against the provided indices with the given search source

 public SearchRequest(String[] indices, SearchSourceBuilder source) {
        this();
        if (source == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("source must not be null");
        }
        indices(indices);
        this.source = source;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, that was also possible in our client, and we already did that. But querieing 2 indexes isnt the problem, querying 2 indexes *with different layouts* is the issue.The geo distance query doesnt like that field2 doesnt exist in index1 and vice versa, because all fields have to be of type geopoint (and a non existing field will be assumed text). I got an answer on the elasticsearch forum which works. I will post a link below.